# File fieldtype in Matrix error: "File cells don’t work within SafeCracker..."

Tags: matrix, safecracker, safecracker-file, files, channel-form

In EE 2.7.0 I'm now getting "File cells don't work within SafeCracker. Use SafeCracker File instead" messages within Matrix cells that formerly used SafeCracker File as fieldtype and have now been changed to File. Same is happening with tests of new entries of File field type used in Matrix.

This is happening on the front end using Channel Form, and safecracker_file module has been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a known bug and will be fixed in a release shortly.

This happened due to changes to Safecracker in EE 2.7 and the subsequent removal of Safecracker File.